# What is the intuition behind Ridge Regression and Adapting Gradient Descent algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, regularization

So I was going through Adaptive Gradient Descent, and learning the intuition behind it: **optimizing the learning algorithm, and getting the model to converge faster.** The way AdaGrad does this, is by dividing the weight vector by the $L_2$ norm. The equation ([copied from here](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#shufflingandcurriculumlearning)), for it, is:

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_{t} - \dfrac{\eta}{\sqrt{G_t}} \odot g_{t}$

where, if i understand correctly, $\sqrt{G_t}$, is the root of the sum of the square of the gradients, which is the $L_2$ norm. Now if I understand correctly, $g_t$ in this case would be considered the "loss function"

Then I got introduced to Ridge Regression, which basically adds the $L_2$ norm (scaled by a lambda) to the loss function. The intuition behind this is **smoothing the loss function so that it doesn't overfit the data**. The equation, ([reworked from here](http://enhancedatascience.com/2017/07/04/machine-learning-explained-regularization/)) is:

$Loss_{L_2} = Loss + \lambda L_2$

So my question, assuming all my understanding so far is correct, is: *What is the intuition behind **adding** as opposed to **dividing by** the $L_2$ norm?*

I understand that you can regularize the loss function in AdaGrad and that they are two separate things, but I still am having trouble wrapping my head around how the math works the way it does. Like why does dividing by the $L_2$ norm make it converge faster? Why doesn't this just smooth the weight vector as well? What is going on here intuitively?

Comment: Regarding your proposed alternative to ridge regression: they're equivalent, modulo a logarithmic/exponential transformation. Read about Bayesian priors for a probabilistic motivation. You will understand that it is equivalent to imposing a Gaussian prior. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adagrad is completely unrelated to ridge regression.  There is no reason to expect that there should be any similarity in their methods.

Adagrad divides by the L2 norm *of the gradient*.  Ridge regression modifies the objective function by adding the L2 norm *of the parameters*.  So even though it looks like the same thing, it's really not; those are two unrelated values.

There's no principle in mathematics that the L2 norm always has to be added or divided.  It's just a number.  It's like seeing one equation where you multiply by 2 and another equation where you add 2 and asking "why does the second one add 2 rather than multiplying by 2?" -- the answer is "why not? there's no reason to expect them to have to use the number 2 in the same way".

Comment: I think that the middle paragraph is what gave me that eureka moment. I thought that the two L2 norms were the same, the fact that it is the norm of the gradient **smoothes out the rate of change of the weight vector** so it makes training more optimized, whereas adding the norm to the cost function **smoothes out the entire shape of the function** by adding the norm. <-- that is the key intuition I was looking for, and you helped me get there, so this is why I'm accepting your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sparse features have small number of updates relative to dense ones, and this is a problem.

The idea of AdaGrad is to make the update speed (learning rate) of a parameter is inversely proportional to the sum of update history of that parameter ($\eta$ / sum of previous updates).

[image]

This makes the small number of updates done to sparse features have a higher learning rate than dense ones.

For more details, you can watch the first 10 minutes of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKCV76N9Ys0&list=PLyqSpQzTE6M9gCgajvQbc68Hk_JKGBAYT&index=42).